# Is there a way to use steam market without delay if I don't have a mobile device?

Tags: steam, steam-community-market

From the googling I've done it seems that without a mobile device (so without the mobile authenticator) I can only buy items on the market immediately. Trading and selling seems to force a 15 day delay. Is this correct? Is there any way at all to circumvent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot trade fast with strangers without the Steam Mobile Authenticator, but you do not necessarily need a smartphone to use it. You only have a 1 day delay with long friends (> 1 year). If you do not have a smartphone capable of running it, you can use an Android Emulator from a trusted source (e.g. Bluestacks). **ALWAYS download both the emulator and the app from trusted sources (e.g. the emulator's website and the playstore). Never download them from random videos or bulk download sites, as the only thing you likely do is get your account hacked.** Afterwards you can run the emulator to do the things you normally would do with the second device. Keep in mind that you are decreasing the security of the Mobile Authenticator by using it on a device where you also use Steam. If your computer is ever compromised, an attacker can access both Steam and your Mobile Authenticator, and is able to authorise it's own transactions.